# How to build and use QtDataVisualization::DeclarativeSurface?

Tags: qt, qml

Specifically, how can I build and link with DeclarativeSurface which is found in Qt5.14.2 source?

I'm developing an app with QML-defined UI and C++ singleton back-end. I'm using Qt v5.14.2. My QML includes a Surface3D item and I want to manipulate it from the C++ back-end.
The C++ back-end locates the Surface3D item in the root window object tree, and its className is "QtDataVisualization::DeclarativeSurface" - it's NOT QtDataVisualization::Q3DSurface, for some reason. Qt's include/QtDataVisualization directory does not have a file named "DeclarativeSurface". A search shows that class DeclarativeSurface is defined in datavisualizationqml2/declarativesurface_p.h. and datavisualizationqml2/declarativesurface.cpp. I include declarativesurface_p.h in my app, invoke DeclarativeSurface methods on the object from C++, and it compiles. But I get "undefined reference" errors at link time.

What is the trick to using DeclarativeSurface? I am using qtcreator v4.5.2

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use DeclarativeSurface, but not officially "supported" and not documented. [See this link.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/113498/how-to-use-qt-s-declarativesurface-in-my-app)

Answer (score 2):

I also have such a problem. Alternatively, I passed separately pointers to surface3D.axisX, surface3D.axisY, surface3D.axisZ and surfaceSeries, and then worked with them.